# comparing accessing digit's position using string and division

Tags: python

I am just wondering which code is better in terms of performance. I mean complexity.

to access number at ten's or hundred's or thousand's position I have two ways.

**1.** to convert it into the string and access the relative position based on whats needed. 
eg

```
num = 567
#if i want to get number at hundred's position
print(str(567)[-2])
```

**2.** Using normal mathematics

```
 #if i want to get number at hundred's position
 num = 567
    print((num // 100) % 10 )
```

Comment: Once you extract the digit in the position, what do you intend to do with it?

Comment: For which definition of "better" ?

Comment: One disadvantage of approach #1 is that it fails if the number is too short; #2 properly returns zero if you ask for a digit that's to the left of any digits actually present in the number.